# Differentiability of $f(x,y) = xy \sin(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}),$ if $(x,y) \not = (0,0), 0$ otherwise.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How to infer the differentiablity of

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}xy \sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right) & (x,y) \not = (0,0) \\ 0 & (x,y)=(0,0) \end{cases}$$

I've started to look at $$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-Ah}{\|h\|}=0$$

where $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$. But this seems to create a very complicated expression about which I don't seem to be able to conclude anything.

Is there something else I can do?

Comment: @Did How are those enough to show differentiability for all $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: At any other point than (0,0), differentiability is (should be!) obvious by the composition of differentiable functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we have to compute $f_x(0,0)=0=f_y(0,0)$. Then $f$ is differtiable at $(0,0)$ iff

$\frac{|f(x,y)|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \to 0$ for $(x,y) \to (0,0)$.

With polar - koordinates it is easy to see that

$\frac{|f(x,y)|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le r|\sin(1/r^2)| \le r =\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Thus,  $f$ is differtiable at $(0,0)$

Comment: Why do you consider differentiability only at $(0,0)$?

Comment: Because it is clear , that f is differentiable at each $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$

Comment: Why is it clear?

Comment: Could you also clarify the polar coordinates inequalities?

Answer (score 0):

Try the inequality $x^2+y^2 \ge 2xy$. It must be differentiable and the derivative at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ must be zero.

In detail, we see
$$\frac{xy\sin\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \le \sqrt{xy}\sin\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$$
and now you can approximate $x$ and $y$ to zero without any problem.

Comment: Why should I try this?

Comment: Because $\frac{xy\sin(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}){\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le \sqrt{xy}\sin(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}) and now you can approximate x and y to zero.

Comment: @mavavilj If the derivative exists, it must be zero, because the function is constant along the axes.

Comment: @Kiwon Lee: Your inequality is not useful ! Better: $$\frac{|xy\sin\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \le \sqrt{|xy|}\sin\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$$

Comment: @Fred For sure! Thanks